# Play framework Ebean Bean caches

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

In the Ebean documentation, it is stated that Ebean support L2 caching, or so called "Bean Caches".

I have this class :

```
@CacheStrategy(readOnly = true)
@Entity
public class Currency extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 5, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String abbreviation;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    private static Finder<Long, Currency> find = new Finder<Long, Currency>(Long.class, Currency.class);

    public static Currency getDollar() {
        return find.where().eq("abbreviation", "USD").findUnique();
    }
}
```

I have this code inside a controller :

```
Currency.getDollar();

Ebean.runCacheWarming(Currency.class);

Currency.getDollar();
```

But when I look in Postgresql logs, I can see that even after the runCacheWarming, a request is executed to the database :

```
2014-01-27 17:34:07 CET LOG:  exécute <unnamed>: select t0.id as c0, t0.abbreviation as c1, t0.name as c2 from currency t0 where t0.abbreviation = $1 

2014-01-27 17:34:07 CET DETAIL:  paramètres : $1 = 'USD'

2014-01-27 17:34:07 CET LOG:  exécute <unnamed>: select t0.id as c0, t0.abbreviation as c1, t0.name as c2 from currency t0 where t0.abbreviation = $1

2014-01-27 17:34:07 CET DETAIL:  paramètres : $1 = 'USD'
```

Do I have to change something in the configuration of my Play project to enable L2 caching ?